# using Mysql and SqlAlchemy in Pyramid Framework

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Pyramid Framework comes with a sample tutorial of sql alchemy that uses sqlite. The problem is that i want to use mysql so i change this

```
sqlalchemy.url = sqlite:///%(here)s/tutorial.db
```

Into this

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql://root:22password@localhost/alchemy
```

when i try to run

```
../bin/pserve development.ini --reload
```

It gives me the following error

```
 File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/sqlalchemy/connectors/mysqldb.py", line 52, in dbapi
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I understand that i should include the dependecies of my app in setup.py but i don't know what to include right now some help please my setup.py looks like this

```
import os
import sys

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
README = open(os.path.join(here, 'README.txt')).read()
CHANGES = open(os.path.join(here, 'CHANGES.txt')).read()

requires = [
    'pyramid',
    'SQLAlchemy',
    'transaction',
    'pyramid_tm',
    'pyramid_debugtoolbar',
    'zope.sqlalchemy',
    ]

if sys.version_info[:3] < (2,5,0):
    requires.append('pysqlite')

setup(name='tutorial',
      version='0.0',
      description='tutorial',
      long_description=README + '\n\n' +  CHANGES,
      classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Framework :: Pylons",
        "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP",
        "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: WSGI :: Application",
        ],
      author='',
      author_email='',
      url='',
      keywords='web wsgi bfg pylons pyramid',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False,
      test_suite='tutorial',
      install_requires = requires,
      entry_points = """\
      [paste.app_factory]
      main = tutorial:main
      [console_scripts]
      populate_tutorial = tutorial.scripts.populate:main
      """,
      )
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding `"MySQLdb"` to the requires list. It was fine with sqlite3 as that comes with python (as of version 2.5), MySQLdb doesn't and needs to be installed separately.

UPDATE:

Try `"mysql-python"` in the requires list instead.

Comment: I tried that already and it gives me the following errors

Installed /home/dennis/Desktop/pyramidtut/tutorial
Processing dependencies for tutorial==0.0
Searching for MySQLdb
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQLdb/
Couldn't find index page for 'MySQLdb' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for MySQLdb
Best match: None

Comment: and when i run import MySQLdb in python shell it doesn't give an error so am sure its properly installed

Comment: Pyramid should have a different set of packages to your system's python shell (it uses a virtualenv with no-site-packages) so you have MySQLdb installed on your system, but not in the pyramid virtualenv.

Comment: am a newbie so what do i do for it to work in the virtualenv?

Comment: Have you tried my updated answer (`"mysql-python"` in the requires list)? With my last comment I was just explaining why you could import MySQLdb but Pyramid couldn't. Pyramid will make sure the things in the requires list are installed in the virtualenv.

Comment: it almost worked but gave me the following error when downloading from sourceforge EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

Answer (score 0):

Okay i Solved my own question by following the directions on this page
http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/install-mysqldb-virtualenv-ubuntu-karmic/

Comment: Please add a short summary of your solution to your answer. Best with the added/changed lines in setup.py

Answer (score 0):

There is the huge list of Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages which are extremely useful for Windows users.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

Solved in ubuntu environment

1. sudo apt-get build-dep python-mysqldb
2. source /bin/active && pip install MySQL-python