# Pyramid + MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pyramid

I'm setting up pyramid app with MySQL DB and I'm facing problem with connection. I'm using python 3.7.2

Here is my sqlalchemy.url:

`sqlalchemy.url = mysql://0.0.0.0:3309/pyramid_framework`

when I try to init the database with alembic:

`alembic -c development.ini revision --autogenerate -m "init"`

This error is shown:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'`

I've already tried add `mysql-python` to my setup.py but this not seem to work.

Has someone sucessfully combined Pyramid with MySQL?

Comment: You should read following thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773380/using-mysql-and-sqlalchemy-in-pyramid-framework

Comment: Found solution after several hours. You need to use ```mysql-connector-python``` beacause MySQLdb is not available for python 3+. So the connection string would look like this ```mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@0.0.0.0:3309/pyramid_framework```

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution worked fine, after some other tries:

Some environments might have conflicts if MariaDB is installed:

```
$ sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then, after activating the python virtualenv:

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
```